# mapping reads using snakemake

Tags: yaml, snakemake

I am trying to run hisat2 mapping using the snakemake.
Basically, I'm using a config.yaml file like this:

```
reads:
    set1: /path/to/set1/samplelist.tab
hisat2:
    database: genome
    genome: genome.fa
    nodes: 2
    memory: 8G
    arguments: --dta
executables:
    hisat2: /Tools/hisat2-2.1.0/hisat2
    samtools: /Tools/samtools-1.3/samtools
```

Then Snakefile:

```
configfile: "config.yaml"
workdir: "/path/to/working_dir/"
# Hisat2
rule hisat2:
    input:
          reads = lambda wildcards: config["reads"][wildcards.sample]
    output:
        bam = "{sample}/{sample}.bam"
    params:
        idx=config["hisat2"]["database"],
        executable = config["executables"]["hisat2"],
        nodes = config["hisat2"]["nodes"],
        memory = config["hisat2"]["memory"],
        executable2 = config["executables"]["samtools"]
    run:
        shell("{params.executable} --dta -p {params.nodes} -x {params.idx} {input.reads} |"
        "{params.executable2} view -Sbh -o {output.bam} -")
# all
rule all:
    input:
        lambda wildcards: [sample + "/" + sample + ".bam"
        for sample in config["reads"].keys()]
```

My samplelist.tab is like this:

```
id  reads1  reads2
set1a set1a_R1.fastq.gz set1a_R2.fastq.gz
set1b set1b_R1.fastq.gz set1b_R2.fastq.gz
```

Any hints how to make this working? I apoligize for a messy script, just started using snakemake.

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: basically, I am not sure it is taking read1 and read2, do I have to create two different input files for that?I made some edits to the script...

Comment: this is the error it is giving me: Error: reads file does not look like a FASTQ file. So I think it is not reading well samplelist.tab file...

Comment: reads should be the actual path to the reads, not the tab-separated file. What does the samplelist.tab look like?

Comment: there is an example of samplelist.tab in the question. Could you give me the example how can I put the paths on the way that it will read me both r1 and r2? also for one set I have more than 1 fastq.gz files.

Comment: Sorry I missed the samplelist.tab. How do you mean to combine the replicates? Since there is a set1a and set1b. Or do you want to align them separately?

Comment: yes, I would like to align all separately, since a and b are tissues, not replicates, but produce one single bam file for set1, i guess I can merge bam files at the end anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

reads = pd.read_csv(config["reads"]['set1'], sep='\t', index_col=0)
def get_fastq(wildcards):
    return list(reads.loc[wildcards.sample].values)

rule hisat2:
    input:
          get_fastq
    ...
```

First you will need to load the samplelist and store this (I did it as a pandas dataframe). Then you can lookup which files belong to that sample name.

**Edit**:

Rewriting the code to look like this is much more readable (in my opinion).

```
rule hisat2:
    input:
          [{sample}_R1.fastq.gz,
           {sample}_R2.fastq.gz]
    ...
```

Comment: thanks, I have another 2 questions, if you prefer I can open a new discussion or post here.

Comment: What if I will list all my files in config.yaml like: set1: set1a_R1.fastq.gz, set1a_R2.fastq.gz, set1b set1b_R1.fastq.gz, set1b_R2.fastq.gz. then in the rules I define both r1 and r2 like this: r1 = lambda wildcards: config["reads"][wildcards.sample]_R1.fastq.gz r2=lambda wildcards: config["reads"][wildcards.sample]_R2.fastq.gz. ISo my questions: 1. how to list the fastq.gz files in the config.yaml? comma separated? 2. The error I ge it that there is a syntax error in the r1 and r2 lines

Comment: Do you actually need to specify two file paths? You could give a basepath, and fill in R1.fastq.gz and R2.fastq.gz in the end.

Comment: somethins like this: set1: set1a, set1b?

Comment: I get the error invalid syntax, so probably something is wrong :((

Comment: My bad, it should be a list. Take a look again at the tutorial for the 'basics'